# Stripe API gives 'SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I've read through the article referring to this in xcode 4.5, but it didn't help me in xcode 5.0.2.

I have a project that compiles successfully. If I add the Stripe framework to my project then it immediately fails to compile and gives me this file not found error for an `#import` made in this header file:

Stripe/Vendor/PaymentKit/PaymentKit Example/PaymentKit Test/PKCardNumberTest.h:9:9: 'SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h' file not found

I do not have the SenTesting framework in my link libraries. If I add it I get an error about it being an OSX library and not an ios. None of the Stripe documentation gives any indication that you need to add this library. I sent their support an email and they told me they don't have any information.

Anyone out there have any suggestions? Again, as soon as I add the framework to my project (and I am making sure it copies the files to my project) it fails to compile.

I tried adding quotes around my framework search paths, but it just changed the error so now Parse/Parse.h was no longer found.

The two framework search paths I have are: `$(inherited)` and `/Users/ctam/Documents/development/Chw`

Comment: Also worth noting that a search of my hard drive does not find SenTest.h anywhere but referenced in the Stripe framework files.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Xcode 5.0 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW302):

> **Unit Testing**
>
> - The CPlusTest unit testing framework has been removed
>   from Xcode 5. To write unit tests for C++ code, use the new XCTest
>   framework and create Objective-C++ (.mm) test case subclasses. 8273037
> - **SenTestingKit and OCUnit are deprecated**. Use the migrator to move to
>   XCTest. 14857574

Answer (score 0):

When you download the Stripe library via the link in their documentation there are a bunch of subfolders for a test project they don't tell you about. I looked through and removed the test application files and everything works fine now. Curious that their explicit directions lead to this problem.